# Simple jQuery click event not working in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have some jQuery that is working just fine in Chrome but when tested it is not working at all. To help troubleshoot it I created a simple button with a very stripped down version of the jQuery that should just show a delete button. However, I'm getting a syntax error in the console and I'm not seeing the alert.

Anyone see what I'm missing? I'm using a CSS class to hook the jQuery code to the button but I don't think that's an issue....unless IE can't handle that.

```js
$(".delete").on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  alert("delete");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 does not support the arrow notation for anonymous functions. Change `(e) => {}` to `function(e) {}` like this:

```js
$(".delete").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("delete");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-danger delete">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete
</button>
```

Comment: Bummer....guess I'm back to refactoring code. It will be nice once Microsoft truly gets out of the browser game.

Comment: Microsoft will probably never get out of the browser business. But remember that IE is being phased out in favor of  their new Edge browser.